# C# - Modify "Flash Player" option programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, flash

I'm here because I have a problem with a webcam and a WPF application.
I develop a webApp that use WebBrowser and a Webcam. I use [WebcamJS](https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs) library that have a flash fallbar to manage the webcam in IE. 
How can I bypass the security popup of flash? How can I write in the Control Panel of the machine where my apps run?
Thanks in advise.

Comment: About which security popup are you talking ? If about which is asking authorization to use the webcam, I think it's impossible to avoid it.

Comment: Yes..I talk about that. Is it possible?

Comment: I would modify by C# the values in the [Website Privacy Settings panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager06.html). How can I made?

Comment: The swf in the page that you have mentioned is just for Flash Player PPAPI (take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28692866/how-to-notify-the-html-container-that-the-swf-has-finished-using-swfobject/28719316#28719316) for more details) but I think you will work with the ActiveX version, no ? In all cases, I think that's really very hard to find where and how Adobe save these data to edit it ! And It's a real question of security, so I don't think that will be a good idea to force user to use his cam !