# URLRequest is not working perfect

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I want to link as3 code to a webpage. I click a button and then go to a web page.  I used navigateToUrl.  When I compile my fla file then the button is working perfect, going to the required webpage.  But without compiling the fla file, when I directly run my swf file, then I cannot go to the required webpage.  Why does this happen?  Here is my code.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

link3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, WebHyperlink);
link3.buttonMode=true;
function WebHyperlink(e:MouseEvent)

{
var myURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.republicofcode.com/");
navigateToURL(myURL, "_blank");

}
```

Comment: I instead of i, sentence spacing, some wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a security exception because Flash Player blocks internet access to your swf file. To see that exception, you can install a Flash Player debug version from [here](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) and to avoid the problem, take a look on [my answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28692866/how-to-notify-the-html-container-that-the-swf-has-finished-using-swfobject/28719316#28719316).

Hope that can help.