# Opening a JavaScript window using a Flash button

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-2

I am trying to create a link in a Flash button (within an SWF Flash object) to a JavaScript window. I used the code below but it didn't work. For Flash I am using AS2.

The code I embedded in the Flash button is as follow:

```
on (release) {
    getURL ("javascript: openWindow ('filex.htm','','scrollbars=yes,width=1100,height=910')")
}
```

Within the HTML's head tag:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function openWindow(theURL,winName,features) { //v2.0
    window.open(theURL,winName,features);
}
//-->
</script>
```

I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Your code looks fine. I think that your problem is that you are testing your app locally and the browser is blocking your SWF to call the JavaScript code, for that, take a look on [my answer of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28719316/2256820), you have all what need to avoid that problem ...

Comment: ahhhh thank you so much. you solved my problem...